# Web Forms multiple submit buttons

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, webforms, submit

I have to make a simple web form app that needs to approve comments for a website. Basically I need to update the status for each comment.

The app is build into an .aspx file with a code.

This is the code to populate the view:

```
<tbody class="body">
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" DataSource="<%# Comments%>" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="col1"><%# Eval("CommentNrCrt") %></td>
            <td class="col2"><%# Eval("CommentText") %></td>
            <td class="col3"><%# Eval("ItemTitle")%></td>
            <td class="col4" data-commentID="<%# Eval("CommentID") %>">
                <input type="button" name="yes" value="yes">
                <input type="button" name="no" value="no">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code behind is ok, gets the data from the DB, populates the view, but now, I am stuck. Initially I planned that if I want a comment to be approved, I hit "yes", then a method for an update is called from the server, makes an update for that comment and viceversa for "no".

My problem is that I don't know how to tell the server what "yes" button I hit, because for each comment I have a "yes" and a "now".

I thought of ajax to send the "data-commentID" as identity, but I don't know how to do it. (with ajax)

Please advice me.

Best regards,
Marius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To accomplish this you could use the Repeater's ItemCommand event. I changed your buttons to ASP.NET buttons and added the CommentID as the CommandArgument and the Yes or No as the CommandText. Then in the ItemCommand event you can retrieve these values and do your database update.

If you wanted to do this using AJAX you could put an ASP.NET UpdatePanel around the repeater.

Here's the change to your repeater and buttons:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Repeater ID="repeater" DataSource="<%# Comments%>" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repeater_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="row">
            <td class="col1"><%# Eval("CommentNrCrt") %></td>
            <td class="col2"><%# Eval("CommentText") %></td>
            <td class="col3"><%# Eval("ItemTitle")%></td>
            <td class="col4">
                <asp:Button ID="btnYes" runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("CommentID") %>' CommandArgument="Yes" Text="Yes" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnNo" runat="server" CommandName='<%# Eval("CommentID") %>' CommandArgument="No" Text="No" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

...And in your code behind:

```
protected void repeater_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    int commentId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    string yesOrNo = e.CommandName;

    //Do your database update here
}
```

I'm not sure if you are C# or VB but my code below is in C# but should be very easy to figure out the VB equivalent.

Alternately you could do the AJAX part using JavaScript or jQuery. If this is the case make this clear in your question and myself or someone might provide another answer.

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your help. I'm going to try this and come back with updates. Code behind is C#.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it:

so I put this: `<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` right after the form.

And I added the OnClick event on each button and the code behind it's working:

```
protected void btnYes_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
       Button btn=(Button)sender;
       string commentID = btn.CommandName;

       //more code
  }
```